# Own values in a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this sql query:

```
SELECT     id, datetime
FROM         (SELECT     id, datetime
                       FROM          DanskAktieAnalyse.dbo.vTest
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT     id, datetime
                       FROM         vTest2) AS articles
ORDER BY datetime
```

Is it possible to get an extra attribute to determin which of the two selects in the union the row comes from? Example 1 if from vTest and 2 if from vTest2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
SELECT     id, datetime, 1 AS ColumnName
```

Where ColumnName is the name you want for these values.

So the full query would be

```
SELECT     id, datetime
FROM         (SELECT     id, datetime, 1 AS ColumnName
                       FROM          DanskAktieAnalyse.dbo.vTest
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT     id, datetime, 2 AS ColumnName
                       FROM         vTest2) AS articles
ORDER BY datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     id, datetime, tname
FROM         (SELECT     id, datetime, 'vTest' as tname
                       FROM          DanskAktieAnalyse.dbo.vTest
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT     id, datetime, 'vTest2' as tname
                       FROM         vTest2) AS articles
ORDER BY datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, just add an expression to the query output:

```
  Select  id, datetime, source
  From (Select id, datetime, 'vtest' source 
        From DanskAktieAnalyse.dbo.vTest 
        Union All
        Select id, datetime, 'vtest2' source 
        From vTest2) AS articles 
  Order By datetime
```

and you really don't need the separate outer query

```
  Select id, datetime, 'vtest' source 
  From DanskAktieAnalyse.dbo.vTest 
    Union All
  Select id, datetime, 'vtest2' source 
  From vTest2
  Order By datetime
```

should work just fine